# How to get the input field value through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, input-field

I have a dynamic table which has the input field in each row. I would like to get the value entered by the user through Javascript. I am able to get the HTML code for the input field 'quantity' but not the value.

Here is the part of the javascript code :

```
var table = document.getElementById("mactable");
var row_count = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
var grand_total = document.getElementById("grand_total");
var grand_price = 0.00;
for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
{
    var price = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
    var quantity = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
    alert(quantity);
    if(isNumber(price))
    {
        var num = parseFloat(price);
        grand_price = grand_price + num;
    }
}
```

Any idea how can it be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading table cell `innerHTML` you can find inner `input` element and then read its `value` property:

```
var quantity = Number(row.cells[2].querySelector('input').value);
```

Here `row.cells[2]` is a `td` element. Using [`querySelector('input')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you can find the first children input.

Also note, that since the value of the field is a string, you might want to cast it to number, for example with `Number` function.